# SqlServer doesn't allow other users to login from other computers

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a server running MS SQL Server 2008 Express. Windows Authentication is used to authenticate the accounts to determine what they can and cannot access.

I have no problems accessing the server from any computer under my username (say, HQ\user1). However, on computers that are not the server, other users cannot access it, even though I've granted them permission. To make it even more strange, if the user account attempts to access the server while logged onto the server, they're not denied.

What am I doing that could cause this to happen, and how can I make it so that all users can access the server?

Answer (score 0):

By default SQL Express does not allow remote connections.

- Open the Surface Area Connection for Services and Connections
- Select your instance, open remote connections and change it from local only to allow remote connections on TCP/IP

Comment: I can connect remotely as long as I use my user account on the other computer.